# Flowers sample crashes on iPhone

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvm-light

I have got a problem with MVVM-Light, it looks like it can't bind to thetextbox.

I am using storyboard on iOS project in Xamarin.

I am testing the same with sample Flowers app downloaded from Github and it looks like there is the same issue. When I hit plus button when I want to add comment to the flower. Simulator is fine, it crashes on debug/release when I deploy to iPhone only.

Attached is a stack trace.

I am not sure how to fix that.
Could you help please?

link to code
[Flowers GitHub](https://github.com/lbugnion/sample-crossplatform-flowers)

[image with stack trace and exact line in CommentViewControler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upgtq.jpg)

Comment: It is much much better to copy and paste code and errors into your question. Screenshots of text is never a good thing.

Comment: Where did you get the source from? Please add a link to your question.

Comment: I believe you are missing something. As far as I remember the first parameter in the SetBinding() method is the source not the target so it should read as: SetBinding (()=> yoursource, ()=> CommentText.Text);

Comment: sorry, project Flowers is on GitHub under this link
https://github.com/lbugnion/sample-crossplatform-flowers
this is something created by MVVM Light author I believe.

Answer (score 0):

That is a problem with the linker. To fix this MVVM Light suggest either changing the linker option (seems not a wise option to me) or subscribing to the event which in your case it'd be:

```
      CommentText.Changed += (sender, e) => {};
```

Kinda ugly but works.

Comment: Thanks that worked, exact name of the event is 'EditingChanged'